# How to export only visible vertices?

Tags: objects, vertices, stl

I'm completely new to Blender. I imported an object and hid the vertices I didn't want with the Box Hide feature in sculpt mode. Now I would like to export to a .stl file only the visible vertices, not the whole thing. Is there a way to delete all hidden vertices or export only visible ones?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Try the *[Box Trim](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools/box_trim.html)* brush. The 2 brushes below the *Box Hide* brush.

Comment: It worked, thank you!